# Redirect any directory URL to a file in that directory, using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Writing a little CMS.

`http://mydomain.com/(somefolder)/` should become

`http://mydomain.com/(somefolder)/filename`

and

`http://mydomain.com/(somefolder)/(somefolder2)/` should become

```
http://mydomain.com/(somefolder)/(somefolder2)/filename
```

and so on recursively. If recursion is too involved, I'd be happy with the two example directory levels.

***filename*** is some fixed string I'll type into .htaccess when I decide what it should be :)

A bonus would be if I can save one redirect if the directory url is lacking a trailing `/`. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1/filename [L]
```

Comment: This is correct. However I'm using canonical URLs that sometimes end with /, and those URLs are also affected. Can I add a conditional check that (somefolder) must exist for the rewrite rule to take effect?

Comment: I dispute that was 5 minutes, since it said 3 minutes ago when I pressed Save Edits. Anyway.

If you're using canonical URLs that sometimes end with /, those URLs are also affected. To avoid 404s on these, add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1/ [L]`. If only a subtree of the folders should be affected, put all 5 lines in the .htaccess in the appropriate base folder.